# How can I encrypt a file in C# using advapi32?

Tags: c#, cryptography, advapi32

I need to encrypt a file in C# using the same process demonstrated in the following Microsoft example doc (but I need SHA instead of MD5).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-encrypting-a-file

I found this question online, which seems to be exactly what I want... However, I'm curious if there is a native way without having to use DLLImports...
[Unable to decrypt with CryptEncrypt/CryptDecrypt in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879111/unable-to-decrypt-with-cryptencrypt-cryptdecrypt-in-c-sharp)

I've been looking at several other sources, but can't seem to find a working solution. This errors out saying my key isn't correct...

```
     byte[] file_contents = File.ReadAllBytes("DescryptedFile.txt");

     string password = "PASSWORD";
     CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider");
     RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
     rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password));
     byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaProvider.Encrypt(file_contents, false);
```

Comment: advapi32 is most likely an unmanaged DLL, so the `import` statements are unavoidable.

Comment: The managed c# methods are often just wrapper that call windows dlls.  What often happens is the c# doesn't include all the options for the windows dlls and c# you cannot override the parameters like in c++.  If you are using a encryption mode (and options) that are supported in c# you do not need the windows dlls.  If you are using an encrytion mode not supported in c# than you have to use the windows dlls.